# Save many-to-many in form manually

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine, save

I have a model with 3 tables Many to 1 to many as below

(shortened schema.yml)

```
PeerEngagement:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    peer_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }

 relations:
   Peer: { local: peer_id, class: Person }

Person:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    nhi: { type: string(7) }
    name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }

  relations:
    Ethnicity: { class: Ethnicity, refClass: PersonEthnicity, local: person_id, foreign: ethnicity_id  }

PersonEthnicity:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    person_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    ethnicity_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
  relations:
    Person:
      class: Person
      local: person_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Ethnicity:
      class: Ethnicity
      local: ethnicity_id
      onDelete: RESTRICT


Ethnicity:
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name: { type: string(50) }
```

Saving these things in auto-generated forms is fine. However in a special case I need to save nhi and ethnicity separately from within PeerEngagementForm.

For saving nhi i have working:

```
function doSave($con=null){

  ...

  if(isset($this->values['nhi'])){
    $this->getObject()->getPeer()->setNhi($this->values['nhi']);
    $this->getObject()->getPeer()->save();
  }

  ...
```

but the same technique doesn't work with

```
if(isset($this->values['ethnicity_list'])){

   $this->getObject()->getPeer()->setEthnicity($this->values['ethnicity_list']);
   $this->getObject()->getPeer()->save();
}
```

The error message I get is that it expects a Doctrine_Collection.

How do I create this collection correctly, or how can I save the many to many relationship from within the top form or action?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put $this->values['ethnicity_list'] in a Collection ?

```
if(isset($this->values['ethnicity_list'])){


$ethnicityLists = new Doctrine_Collection('Ethnicity');
foreach($this->values['ethnicity_list'] as $ethnicityList){
  $ethnicityLists->add($ethnicityList);
}
$peer = $this->getObject()->getPeer();
$peer->setEthnicity($ethnicityLists);
$peer->save();

}
```

Should work, I do it the same way I think.